# Comparing cells in a column (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to list the comparisons of each two cells in the same column. Say, I have some values in the cells  A1,A2,A3,..,A11. I'm trying to create a table such that in each cell contains the minimum value of two Ai and Aj (i is not equal to j). i.e min(Ai,Aj)=x. However, I managed to write something that helps me to compare A1 with other Ai's. In each time, I need to change what I wrote so as to get the comparison of A2 to other cells (except A1). How can I manage to get the list once? Thanks in advance.

This is what happens when I run my code.

[image: []

This is I am trying to get.

[image: []

```
    Sub comparisonfunction2()


    Dim ds As Long  ' number of files
    Dim i As Long   'loop variable



     Range("A1").Select

     ds = 12
     yp = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Count



For i = 2 To ds

If Cells(2, 1) < Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
    Cells(2, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy

Cells(i + 1, 5).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Else
Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
Selection.Copy

Cells(i + 1, 5).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End If


Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing you can do this with a formula and not use VBA (?)

Comment: How come? If you mean using min function, I need to type that for 55 times.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `=MIN($A$2,A3)`, drag the formula